# Making nav (.navbar) change background colour on scroll down isnt working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I am struggling to make the nav class .navbar change background-color on scroll down. I've used this code and some others, it's not working no matter what I try to implement. I am trying to get the nav to add the alt-color class after the view has left the top of the page

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
        navbar = $('.navbar');

    if (scrollPos > 10) {
      navbar.addClass('alt-color');
    } else {
      navbar.removeClass('alt-color');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
    transition: 0.2s all linear;
    background-color: #212121;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar.alt-color {
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar">
</nav>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the jQuery library? PS instead of 5 lines of code you could just: `navbar.toggleClass('alt-color', scrollPos > 10);`

Comment: I've converted your code into a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193), but it's not clear to me how this demonstrates the problem.  Can you update it?

Comment: @David I want to make the navbar background colour white after it has scrolled 1px past the top of the screen

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: @tacoshy do you have an example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said, you do not need to use jQuery. JQuery becomes more and more outdated and vanilla JS can do this as easy.

Simply add an Event Listener to the window: `window.addEventListener` and check for the `scroll` event.

Then you can add the class there based on a condition with `classList.toggle`. Toggle allows for a second parameter as condition. In this case: `this.scrollY > 10`

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  const NAVBAR = document.querySelector('nav');
  NAVBAR.classList.toggle('alt-color', this.scrollY > 10);
})
```

```css
.navbar {
    transition: 0.2s all linear;
    background-color: #212121;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar.alt-color {
    background-color: blue;
}

/* added for demo purpose */
body {
  min-height: 800vh;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar"></nav>
```

Comment: @tacosy thank you for explaining, this still doesn't work for me

Comment: @tacosy your solution worked, needed !important on the alt-color background color! thank you